# Subset files in a list that are stored in a directory

Tags: python, list, file, directory

I have a list of files that looks like:

```
 list1= [abc.txt,def.txt, pqr.txt]
```

I want to keep this files in directory and remove all other files.

My code to find the files is:

```
list1= [/home/usr/Documents/abc.txt,/home/usr/Documents/def.txt, /home/usr/Documents/pqr.txt]

def search(trace,file_path)
   i=0
   for files in os.listdir(file_path):

    #print(i,' : Reading file: ' , files)
        if files == trace:
            i=i+1
            LOG.info(" %d Reading file : %s" % (i,files))

for traces in list1:
        trace = traces.rsplit('/',1)[1]
        print(trace)
        search(trace,file_path)
```

This read subset of files but I want to delete all other files so that it will parse the directory quickly because currently it seaches for names of 4000 files to match 37 names. Hence, the iterations it takes would be 37 *4000 , or I want to do it in fewer iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use glob module to find the filenames matching the pattern
Check below example

```
import glob
print glob.glob("/home/usr/*/abc.txt")
```

you can check documentation here : 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html